# Stop Googe Sheet from refreshing HTML data

Tags: html, google-sheets, page-refresh, google-apps-script-addon

I have a sheet that pulls alot of finance data from alot of web pages using HTML. Problem is that it slows down alot. Plus it starts giving errors due to high number of HTMLs and etc.. i looked for the following solutions:

1. Having an app script to make refreshes controlled..(not so effective)
2. Any way i could copy paste the old data automatically till new data comes in and updates old pasted values..(also not effective as i couldnt find an automated method)
3. Tried finding a way to play with google sheet auto-calculations to help....(also failed in that)

IS there a way to ristrict the sheet from auto refreshing so many times...?

Comment: Hello Awais, how are you pulling the data right now? Are you using a script/custom function?

Comment: Hi..I am pulling data through importHTML..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en) you can see that:

> Functions that pull data from outside the spreadsheet recalculate at the following times:
>
> - ImportRange: 30 minutes
> - ImportHtml, ImportFeed, ImportData, ImportXml: 1 hour
> - GoogleFinance: may be delayed up to 20 minutes

If you want to recalculate the value for your `importHTML` functions with a lower frequency you should definitely use Apps Script to do the data fetch and then populate your Spreadsheet with the information.

You can use UrlFetchApp class on Apps Script to get the data and define your timing logic for the updates.

```
function myAppScriptFunction() {

    var urls = ["your-website-url1", "...", "your-website-urlN"];
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(urls);
    //... Parse the response and store the information you need in a table-like data structure

    // Let's assume the variable parsedResponseData is created
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    ss.getRange("your-range").setValues(parsedResponseData);

}
```

You should now wrap your function in your custom time logic to manage the updates.
You can achieve this with a time-driven trigger on Apps Script.

```
function triggerSetup() {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('myAppScriptFunction')
          .timeBased()
          .everyHours(6)
          .create();
}
```

### References:

[Time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

[UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

[Quota Limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. however i noticed one issue.. This app script needs URL for web pages. i use multiple Web pages .. i cant give URLs for all web pages.. Please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: currently i am using app script in this video.. it help but not perfect solution..
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V82CMgR8EgU&list=PLvRl9m-5lG0nwFIViWROSan2b9Z-9ODdX

Comment: I updated the code to enable you to pass the UrlFetchApp more than one URL.

Comment: Still not enough as there are so many Urls.. but thanks anyway.

Comment: Hello Awais, there is no length limit for the `urls` array in the `fetchAll()` method. It has [size limits](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) which actually apply for every Google Apps Script application.

Comment: Noted. if i am fetching let say these two 
1. https://www.finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?p=AAPL
2. https://www.finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/key-statistics?p=MSFT

will giving   >>>https://www.finance.yahoo.com<<<   work for script?

Comment: If [finance.yahoo.com](https://www.finance.yahoo.com/) contains all the information that you need, yes. Otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this addon which freezes your spreadsheet on demand:

**https://gsuite.google.com/marketplace/app/spreadsheet_freezer/526561533622**

[image: 0]

Comment: Tried your suggestion .. not helping.. but thanks anyway.